# What is $\cos^2\left( x^2\right)+\sin^2\left( x^2\right)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, vectors, euclidean-geometry

Suppose I put $x^2=t$ then I get $\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1$. Actually, this is based on the velocity of a particle in vector notation.

> [image]

So the speed (magnitude of velocity of the particle)  keeps on increasing as we move in a clockwise direction. But for a vector traced by $c(t) =(\cos(t), \sin(t))$ the speed is constant(magnitude of velocity. 
How can this be true if the mathematically trace the same curve i.e a unit circle?

Comment: Haven't you ever driven a car on the same road with different speeds?

Comment: You can take the same curve at different speeds and agree that it is the same curve, can't you?  A race-car goes around a curve at the track... on 3 consecutive laps it traces the exact same path, but at different speeds each time.   Lap one it his the curve at 100 mph.  On lap 2, the caution flag was out and it took the curve at 35 mph.  On lap 3, it entered the curve at 100 mph, and exited the curve at 150, accelerating along the way.

Comment: Sure, they trace the same curve, but one accelerates as it goes.

Comment: The answer to your question in the title is $1$. But you are not asking that question in the body of your post.

Comment: Actually the particle travels in the anticlockwise direction.

Answer (score 3):

Although the magnitude of the position vector is constant, that is not the speed of the particle.

The velocity vector is

$$\mathbf{v}=(-2t\sin t^2,2t\cos t^2)$$

so the speed is

$$ \Vert\mathbf{v}\Vert=2\vert t\vert $$

Answer (score 1):

I believe you meant counterclockwise*.

Anyway, there is nothing strange about this. Picture you and Usain Bolt running. You both describe the same picture (a straight line), but of course his velocity and acceleration are very different of yours.

Hope the above gives you a bit of intuition. The whole difference is in the parameters adopted.

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ you have $r = 1$ all the time and $\theta=t^2$.

Now, $\|\mathbf v\|^2 = \dot r^2 + r^2 \dot\theta^2$, where $\dot{\phantom{x}}$ denotes derivative with respect to $t$.

We have $\dot r=0$, but $\dot\theta = 2t$ so $\|\mathbf v\| = 2|t|$.